# Is average velocity equal to displacement per unit time OR displacement divided by time?

Tags: kinematics, time, velocity, definition, displacement

I had looked for the definition of average velocity in books like Resnick Halliday, Tipler ' Sears zemansky but no book writes average velocity as displacement per unit time although in these books the word "per unit" is used while defining average density or average work . In case of average velocity they write it as displacement divided by time. I feel there might be some technical problem in using the words " displacement per unit " so what is the problem in usage of "displacement per unit time"

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, when you perform division operation $A/b$, then what you do actually - you *scale* $A$, with a scaling operation $A'=b^{-1}A$. When looked this way, i.e. $v\equiv s' = t^{-1}s$, speed *is* displacement per unit time.

However, this has problems with dimensional analysis. Units of speed and displacement does not match. So while mathematically scaling operation tampers with same variable, physically meaning of transformed variable is totally different.  I.E. physically $v \ne s'$, simply because units does not match, in SI unit system speed $v$ is measured in $m/s$, while displacement $s$ - in meters. This may be the main cause why books tends to avoid "... per unit" definitions.

That being said, *"per unit"* definitions are very useful for broadening physical intuition and introducing new concepts. Say you are introducing a concept of pressure. Saying "divide $F/A$ and you will get pressure" doesn't helps much to understand what pressure IS actually. Saying "homogeneous and constant force pushing each unit of area across all surface" says a lot more to people already knowing concept of force.